# File transfer using UDP

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have written a program to transfer a file from client side to server side. The program runs without any errors. Also the file is created on the destination path. But when i try to open  the file the gedit crashes. The program should transfer audio,video,text file.I know UDP should not be used to transfer file as it may be corrupted but i have to do it as assignment. Following code is for text file transfer.

Server.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class server
{
            public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
            {

                        DatagramSocket dsoc=new DatagramSocket(8008);
                        byte b[]=new byte[787734];                
            byte c[];                   
            String pac ;
            File file = new File("/home/san_16398/ip2.java");
         FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);


                        while(true)
                        {
                                    DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(b,b.length);
                                    dsoc.receive(dp);
                                    pac =new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
                                  System.out.println(pac);                             

                        }

                   pac.getBytes();
                      f.write(b);
                      f.flush();
                      f.close();
            }
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class client
{
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
            public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
            {         
                        byte b[]=new byte[787734];
                        FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream("/home/san_16398/ip.java");
                        DatagramSocket dsoc=new DatagramSocket(2000);
                        int i=0;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        while(f.read(buffer) != -1)
                        {
                                    b[i]=(byte)f.read();
                                    i++;
                        }                     
                        f.close();
                        dsoc.send(new DatagramPacket(b,i,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),8008));
            }

}
```

Comment: `"The program runs without any errors."` - After the program runs, have you validated that the resulting file is identical to the original file?  If it's not, I'd call that an error.

Comment: The program runs fine even the file named ip2.java is created but when i try to open it the gedit stops working.

Comment: In other words @David is correct, it is an error, not 'runs without any errors'.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while(f.read(buffer) != -1){
  b[i]=(byte)f.read();
```

- first you are reading **into** your buffer object - to then never make use of the `buffer` array
- and then you read a single byte *again*
- to then read into the buffer again

Long story short: either use the `read(buffer)` **or** use the single byte `read()` *consistently*.

And beyond that: you also forgot to **check** that the file you intend to read fits into the buffer that you want to transmit to the server!

Finally: you are also trying to do *too many** things at once. Instead: focus on the **different** parts of this work, like:

- first write code that reads a file
- then enhance that to create a **local** copy of that file
- and then, when that works, instead of creating a local copy, send to a remote server.

Comment: so,what changes shoud I make?

Comment: @Alex Good observation. I was way to quick answering here. Fixed my input.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte b[]=new byte[787734];
// ...
while(f.read(buffer) != -1){
    b[i]=(byte)f.read();
    i++;
}
dsoc.send(new DatagramPacket(b,i,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),8008));
```

This is complete and utter nonsense. You're reading up to 787734 bytes and throwing them away, and then reading one byte, if there is one, and then apparently attempting to send a datagram of size up to 787734, which is impossible. It should be:

```
byte b[]=new byte[534];
// ...
int count;
while((count = f.read(b)) != -1){
    dsoc.send(new DatagramPacket(b,count,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),8008));
}
```

and then you have to take care of duplicate datagrams, datagrams not received, datagrams received out of order, ...

And calling `File.exists()` and `File.createNewFile()` when you're using a `FileOutputStream` is a complete waste of time at best, but when you call them *after* creating the `FileOutputStream` you are liable to clobber the file that is being written to, depending on the platform. Remove.

Comment: @SandeepChavan Whatever that means. Did you have another question?